# How to stop infinite loop of javascript while detecting browser language

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My objective is to detect the user's language and redirect them to either a French page or English, with English being the default.  This works if I put the code on the French page only and try to open the French page, this auto detects and loads the English.  If I have the code on both then it just gets stuck in an infinite loop.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the code.

```
<script language="javascript"> 

var langcodes=new Array("en", "fr", "default") ;

var langredirects=new Array("http://defaulten.asp", 
"http://default-fr.asp", 
"http://default.asp"); 

var languageinfo=navigator.language? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage ;
var gotodefault=1 ;

function redirectpage(dest){ 
if (window.location.replace) 
window.location.replace(dest) 
else 
window.location=dest 
} 

for (i=0;i<langcodes.length-1;i++){ 
if (languageinfo.substr(0,2)==langcodes[i]){ 
redirectpage(langredirects[i]) 
gotodefault=0 
break 
} 
} 

if (gotodefault) 
redirectpage(langredirects[langcodes.length-1]) 

</script>
```

Comment: You need to detect if you're on an english page and **NOT** redirect if the chosen language is english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you don't re-direct if you are already on the correct page e.g.

```
if (languageinfo.substr(0,2)==langcodes[i]) {
    gotodefault = 0;
    var redirPage = langredirects[i];
    if (redirPage != document.URL)
        redirectpage(redirPage);
    break 
}
```

Also, if `en` is the default I wouldn't have a specific page for that i.e. `defaulten.asp`. I would only provide language specific pages i.e. `default-fr.asp` / `default-us.asp`, if you followed this approach your code would be even simpler e.g.

```
var languageinfo = navigator.language ? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage;
languageinfo = languageinfo == "en" ? "" : languageinfo;
var langUrl = sprintf("http://default%s.asp", languageinfo);
if (document.URL != langUrl)
    redirectpage(langUrl);
```

Comment: thanks for providing an answer.  Your first answer was exactly what I was looking for.  I will try your second answer as well.  THANKS

Comment: @Ruger no worries, the second answer was more just to simplify the code a little (i.e. no loops or hard-coded urls).

Comment: Another question if you don't mind. I have a link for the user to select their language after the redirect. Problem is it continues to redirect. Is it possible to stop the redirect if the user makes a manual selection?

Comment: @Ruger in that scenario I would recommend you store a cookie. That means once they select their preferred language it will be remembered next time they visit.